# Tableau - how to show a legend for a stacked bar chart?

Tags: tableau-api, legend

I have a Tableau bar chart which is a stacked chart.

I am wondering how to "turn on" display of the legend to show what the colour values mean in the stacked chart ?

Actually I have spotted the legend now .. (it is on the right under the filters (if any) and not in the main body/canvas of the report / graph ..

I think the answer is Legend settings are via the "show/hide cards" button on ribbon (third button in from right) (is this correct?) (Is this the only way?)..
(i.e. am wondering if the show/hide cards button is also available via menus? )

Legend formatting is via the menu Format choice .. Legend menu options ..

I am now wondering about legend positioning and how this will appear in PDF..

I think this Legend position is setup under the file | page setup options ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're asking so I'm running the risk of getting marked down myself...

1. The only way to change the Legend visibility is on the ribbon.
2. Positioning on PDF is via File > Page setup if you are printing a sheet, but by actual placement if you're using a dashboard.

Personally, I start to worry when people talk about printing to PDF.  You lose too much functionality.  That said, I would prefer creating a dashboard to control legend location accurately.